# Will a snowball viburnum thrive in the San Francisco bay area (Fremont)?

Tags: plant-health

I'm thinking of gifting someone with a [snowball viburnum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viburnum_opulus) for Christmas. Will it live alright in the bay area (specifically, Fremont)? I heard that the soil may cause some issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty much everything from a temperate climate can live in the bay area. I've seen similar viburnums for sale at local nurseries so it should be fine